# Connection between DateTime and Calendarsystem, to calculate time differences

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, jodatime

i have a MySQL Database which contains several timestamps e.g. startDate and endDate. Now i want the difference between the two timestamps. 
(I read a lot about the advantages of joda time, but did not work with the included java implementation.)

I do not know if i understand the concepts correctly:

I need a formatter e.g. DateTimeFormatter to format the startDate string into a valid dateTime format.

```
//yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.m, the last .m, is for the miliseconds i got from jdbc/mysql
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.m");
String startDate = resultSet.getString("StartDateInMySQLDB");
DateTime dateTime = formatter.parseDateTime(startDate);
```

Now i have a DateTime object. However i need a connection to a calendar system, to e.g. calculate the time between two dates. But is not a simple time of 24h for a day (i found several solutions with joda and without a calendar). I need something like a work-time: e.g. 09:00 AM to 05:00 PM (Monday to thursday)

Therefor i thought, i need a calendar sytem, but i do not know to connect datetime and the calendar system correctly.

Comment: I don't understand your last part. What do you mean by - *But is not a simple time of 24h for a day*?

Comment: a day has 24hours but, i want to calculate 24hours between two days. e.g. startDate = monday morning 9:00, endDate = tuesday morning 9:00, result = 8hours. Because it is a working day: from 09:00 AM to 05:00 PM (8hours)

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).